# UIButton receives touchEvents at the wrong position after a CABasicAnimaton

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, touch, cabasicanimation

I would like to add an animation to a button which make the button remove point A to point B.
And the follow code can do it.But the weird thing is when the button is moved,it can not detect the touch any more.
If you and if I tap the original location of the button,it can trigger the button event.Is anything missing in my code?
Please help me.

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender
{

UIButton    *lineButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[lineButton addTarget:self   action:@selector(press:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[lineButton setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:lineButton];
CABasicAnimation *lineAnimation;


lineAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[lineAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[lineAnimation setDuration:0.15];


[lineAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[lineAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100, 200, 50, 50);
    lineAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(50, 50)];
    lineAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect),   CGRectGetMidY(rect))];
[lineAnimation setAutoreverses:NO];
[lineButton.layer addAnimation:lineAnimation forKey:@"line"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the new frame and layer to your button's frame/layer after the addAnimation method like:

```
lineButton.frame = rect
lineButton.layer.frame = rect
```

Or you can simply use animation blocks (Easier to use, code looks nice, etc..) like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 animations:^{
  lineButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 50, 50);
}];
```

Comment: you are welcome. :) just remember to set this answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

In your interfacebuilder set the autoresizing property on buttons and setframes properly. If you rotate a device or simulator, then frame resizing will automatically be done. Then you will lose original frame.