# UIButton receives touches at the wrong position after CABasicAnimaton applied

Tags: ios, events, uibutton, touch, cabasicanimation

I need to add an animation to UIButton - simple moving animation. When I do this, the button moves, but the click area of that button remains at old position:

```
UIButton *slideButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[slideButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[slideButton setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:slideButton];

CABasicAnimation *slideAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[slideAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[slideAnimation setDuration:1];
[slideAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
[slideAnimation setAutoreverses:NO];

slideAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)];
slideAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[slideButton.layer addAnimation:slideAnimation forKey:@"slide"];
```

I already saw an answer to change the frame of the button at the end of the animation (like here [UIButton receives touchEvents at the wrong position after a CABasicAnimaton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395335/uibutton-receives-touchevents-at-the-wrong-position-after-a-cabasicanimaton)) But it's not my case because I should give possibility to user to click on the button while it's moving... Also, I can't use another approaches (like NSTimer) as a replacement for CABasicAnimation because I will have a complex path to move the object...

Thanks for Your help!

Comment: possibly someone knows how to get REAL position of the button, from the CABasicAnimation object? It would save me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found that it's not really possibly to do with CABasicAnimation. Coz animation cycle animates a layer object inside the view, but the view itself remains unchangeable, no matter what properties has been set to CABasicAnimation object.

After a few hours of googling I found a cool feature developed by MICHAEL TYSON:
http://atastypixel.com/blog/key-path-based-property-animation/

I improved it a little bit - added: autoreverse, repeatCount, cumulative, timeOffset, byValue.. And voila! Almost the same CABasicAnimation - but able to animate frame!